# Proof of an Abstract Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning, conditional-expectation, bayes-theorem, radon-nikodym

In Björk (2009) a Bayes' theorem is given by

> Assume that $X$ is a random variable on $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ and let $Q$ be another probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ with Radon-Nikodym derivative 
>   $$L = \frac{dQ}{dP} \; \; \text{on }  \mathcal F.$$
>   Let $G$ be a sigma-algebra such that $G \subset \mathcal F$. Then 
>   $$E^Q[X\mid G] = \frac{E^P[LX\mid G]}{E^P[L\mid G]}.$$

The proof is to show that the integral over any $A \in G$ of the both sides of 
$$E^Q[X\mid G]E^P[L\mid G] = E^P[LX\mid G]$$
is the same quantity.

Starting with the left hand side,

> $$\begin{aligned}
> \int_AE^Q[X\mid G]E^P[L\mid G]dP &= \int_AE^P\left[L\cdot E^Q[X\mid G]\mid G\right]dP \\
> &=\int_AL\cdot E^Q[X\mid G]dP
> \\
> &= \int_AE^Q[X\mid G]dQ
> \\
> &= \int_AXdQ.
> \end{aligned}$$

The first equality follows from the fact that $E[X\mid G]$ is $G$-measurable. Why the second equality follows? My guess is that he moves $L$ inside the expectation under $Q$ and then applies the law of iterated expectations. However for this $L$ has to be $G$-measurable which is not generally the case since it is defined of $\mathcal F$ which is bigger than $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to read the second equality backwards, what it says is nothing but the definition of the conditional expectation.